# TypeError: this.props.clickitem is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I have created `RoundedButton` component as a child component. I am sending click button value into parent component using

```
  _handleButtonClick(item) {
    this.props.clickitem(item.buttonText);
  }
```

Compiler throws an error

```
TypeError: this.props.clickitem is not a function
RoundedButton._handleButtonClick
D:\ReactJS\xxx\src\RoundedButton.js:8
   5 |  state = {};
   6 | 
   7 |  _handleButtonClick(item) {
>  8 |    this.props.clickitem(item.buttonText);
   9 |  }
  10 | 
  11 |  render() {
View compiled
```

RoundedButton.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class RoundedButton extends Component {
  state = {};

  _handleButtonClick(item) {
    this.props.clickitem(item.buttonText);
  }

  render() {
    let buttonText = this.props.text;
    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        className="Button"
        onClick={this._handleButtonClick.bind(this, { buttonText })}
      >
        {buttonText}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default RoundedButton;
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.clickitem = this.clickitem.bind(this);
  }

  clickitem(buttonText) {
    console.log(buttonText);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="AppTitle">
        <b>Score:</b>
        <div>
          <RoundedButton text="Rock" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
          <RoundedButton text="Paper" />
          <RoundedButton text="Scissors" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Im guessing there is some code missing or `_handleButtonClick` is not being invoked from where you think it is.

Comment: have you tried `this.tap.bind(this)` in `App.js`?

Comment: Use `propTypes` to check which component passing wrong `clickitem`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

Comment: Can you make sure that this.props.clickitem exists in RoundedButton component? My guess is that it's undefined. Try to console.log it.

Comment: @Williams tried your code, it's working properly check the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/e70wpwdy/

Comment: BTW check you do have `clickitem={this.tap} ` not `clickitem={this.tap()} `

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo `_handleButtonClick` is being invoked in my case, I tried to debug with some logging

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I have `<RoundedButton text="Rock" clickitem={this.clickitem} />` see my updated question

Comment: @D-reaper Do you mean `console.log(this.props.clickitem)` ?

Comment: @Williams Try adding `static propTypes = {clickitem: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired}` to your `RoundedButton` component. And check console for warnings.

Comment: @Williams yes, do that inside Rounded component. What do you get?

Comment: @D-reaper I am getting undefined inside `_handleButtonClick(item) {
      console.log(this.props.clickitem); }`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko inside render method ?

Comment: @Williams are you also passing `clickitem={this.clickitem}` to the other RoundedButton component? the ones with text="scissors" and text="paper"

Comment: @Williams Inside class definition.

Comment: @D-reaper You got it man!! Can you answer so I can accept it :) I was missing to add `clickitem={this.clickitem}` in other `RoundedButton`

Comment: Thanks a lot @MayankShukla you were right :) I didn't paste complete code as I was not aware of it that matters.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thanks you too :)

Comment: @Williams I do recommend you to declare prop types for your components. [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html). You and the rest of your team will be warned about incorrect or missing property before running into error like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works. However for the RoundedButton with the text set to "rocks". However you might have forgotten to put clickitem props on the other two RoundedButton components

```js
class RoundedButton extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  _handleButtonClick(item) {
    this.props.clickitem(item.buttonText);
  }

  render() {
    let buttonText = this.props.text;
    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        className="Button"
        onClick={this._handleButtonClick.bind(this, { buttonText })}
      >
        {buttonText}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.clickitem = this.clickitem.bind(this);
  }

  clickitem(buttonText) {
    console.log(buttonText);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="AppTitle">
        <b>Score:</b>
        <div>
          <RoundedButton text="Rock" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
          <RoundedButton text="Paper" clickitem={this.clickitem}/>
          <RoundedButton text="Scissors" clickitem={this.clickitem}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```